# Java shutdown hook is ignored (?) when using HCL Domino NotesThread

Tags: java, hook, lotus-domino, shutdown

I'm currently developing a Vaadin-based program in Java which extracts documents from Domino databases and writes them to a MongoDB collection. The program works perfectly but has one small flaw:

Currently i've found no way to stop the program other then send "KILL" to the process. My shutdown hook/signal handler is totally ignored. I've narrowed down the problem to a single line of code:

*NotesThread.sinitThread();*

When i remove this line, the hook works perfectly and my program is shutdown properly. When the line is inserted, then the hook is never called.

Here is some example code:

```
private boolean running = true;

...

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        NotesGC.runWithAutoGC(() -> {
            NotesThread.sinitThread() // --> "Kills" all signal handling
            Session session = NotesFactory.createSession();
            
            while (running) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Running ...");
            }

            session.recycle();

            return null;
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        NotesThread.stermThread();
    }
}

public void kill() {
        System.out.println("Killed!");
        this.running = false;
}

...

Signal.handle(new Signal("TERM"), sig -> runner.kill()); // Signal handler from main-method
```

I've asks friends and colleagues and nobody ever had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

NotesGC.runWithAutoGC
As I see you are using Domino JNA, a side project.
It use the domino CAPI.
It's open source: https://github.com/klehmann/domino-jna
You can create issue ticket or ask question.
BTW, func "runWithAutoGC" call initThread() in his body.
This link for source code: https://github.com/klehmann/domino-jna/blob/master/domino-jna/src/main/java/com/mindoo/domino/jna/gc/NotesGC.java

Comment: Yes, i'm using Domino-JNA, but the problem also occurs with the "normal" Notes-Java-API (Just remove the "NotesGC.runWithAutoGC"-construct). I just copied and testing example which i generated from my production code.

Comment: Try typing the names Thread and / or threadID. Looks like it different Theards.